# Hadoop Error in windows

Tags: java, hadoop

I have successfully installed hadoop. However, when I run hadoop commands, it prompts following error:

```
 C:\>hadoop version
'JAVA_HOME' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 Hadoop 2.7.3
 Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 
 baa91f7c6bc9cb92be5982de4719c1c8af91ccff Compiled by root on 2016- 
 0818T01:41ZCompiled with protoc 2.5.0 From source with checksum 
 2e4ce5f957ea4db193bce3734ff29ff4 This command was run using /C:/hadoop- 
 2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar
```

I checked and fixed my Environment variables for JAVE_HOME and PATH. I found no issues with path, but above error persists while running hadoop commands or connecting to HDFS. Following is output when I run javac command.

```
C:\>javac
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
-g                         Generate all debugging info
-g:none                    Generate no debugging info
-g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
-nowarn                    Generate no warnings
-verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
-deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: while setting path did you miss "$"? or in case of windows it is "%JAVA_HOME%"
Setinng JAVA_HOME in your "PATH environment variable like "%JAVA_HOME%" does it.
to check this do : echo "%JAVA_HOME%"

Comment: Do you want to say, I need to put "%" symbol before and after "JAVA_HOME" ?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you need to `JAVA_HOME` (you typed `JAVE_HOME`) in the Environment Variables from Control Panel.

You should not need to edit any Hadoop scripts otherwise, but in scripts, it would be `%JAVA_HOME%`. So, in the `PATH` variable, you can have something like

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin:%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
```

---

If you want to use Hadoop 2.7.x, then it should be (currently) 2.7.7 to catch bug fixes + patches

Comment: I guess, after installing some windows utilities for Hadoop, I got that fixed. Thanks any way. Do you have any expierence RHadoop?

Comment: I am not an R developer, no